# Return resolved promise value

Tags: javascript, promise

```
  const displayCharacters =  async () => { 
    if(filteredCharacters !== 'default'){
      const a = filteredCharacters.map(e => e.name);
      const options = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({ 'data' : a })
      };

      const b = await fetch("/image",options).then(res => res.json())
      return b; 

    }else{
      return "yikes";
    }
  }


  console.log(displayCharacters());
```

I have this fetch request but when I log the results this is what i see :

```
Promise {<resolved>: "yikes"}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]: "yikes"
```

I just want the promiseValue and not this whole thing around it. How do i do this?

Comment: You can't. Async functions always return promises. Either call .then on the promise, or put your code in an async function and await the promise.

Comment: `displayCharacters().then(data=>console.log(data))` that's how it gonna work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `async` function returns a promise instantly, without waiting for the promise to resolve. You may instead console.log inside the function:

```
  const displayCharacters =  async () => { 
    if(filteredCharacters !== 'default'){
      const a = filteredCharacters.map(e => e.name);
      const options = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({ 'data' : a })
      };
      try {
        const b = await fetch("/image",options).then(res => res.json());
        console.log(b);

        //the better practice is however, to do like:
        const b = await fetch("/image",options)
        const result = await b.json(); 
        console.log(result );
      }
      catch(err) {
         console.log(err);
      }

    }else{
      console.log("yikes");
    }
  }


displayCharacters();
```

Comment: The `async` does "return a promise instantly", but more importantly it allows the code to return the response directly from an asynchronous function like `fetch()` without a callback. The `await` expression allows this by waiting for the response  from the `fetch()` call before continuing execution within the async function. Note: You will want to handle uncaught exceptions as await does not so best to wrap the request in a `try...catch`. [See docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Comment: @segFault, thanks for the suggestion, my intention was to answer his specific question by keeping the code simple, but you're right It's worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

The best way that i know to use fetch goes something like this:

```
const displayCharacters =  async () => { 
  if(filteredCharacters !== 'default'){
    const a = filteredCharacters.map(e => e.name);
    const options = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({ 'data' : a })
    };

    const b = await fetch("/image",options)
      .then(res => {
        // Handle API Errors
        if (!res.ok) {
          throw Error(res.statusText);
        }
        // Return if no errors
        return res.json();
      })
      // this is the data you want
      .then(data => data)
      // it will only reject on network failure or if anything prevented the request from completing
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.message)
      });

    return b; 

  }else{
    return "yikes";
  }
}
```

Basically you chain two thens and a catch to completely understand the response
- the first then checks for api level errors
- second then gets you the data
- catch is invoked in case when it is not able to reach the api itself like connection issues